# PHP how to clone $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

Edit: Thanks for the answers, I realised that as I'm serving all pages from the index.php using FallbackResource that every time the script is loaded the `_$SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is going to be updated. I am going to store the root folder in a textfile or database entry to be accessed by index.php.

Thanks again

I am wondering how to get a fixed value from `$GLOBALS['rooturi'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as it updates when I call it.

I am setting it in my index.php to set a root path for including images in another script. I have tried using `__DIR__."/images/"` but I do not want the filesystem location (C:\xampp\htdocs\file1\file2\website\images) rather the URL version (/website/images/)

```
$GLOBALS['rooturi'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

The problem is when I call it in another script it uses the new scripts `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ie. (website/images/3/images/3)

I am using .htaccess with `FallbackResource index.php`

Thanks in advance

Comment: cant you just use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: No, that returns the filesystem path (C:\~\website) and I'm looking for the path to use with <img> (http://127.0.0.1/~/website)

Comment: sorry that was wrong, but im not sure what value you want the domain name? any relative value will depend on where you are in the file system at the time. if you want `$var/file.jpg` you will have to know your resolved image path

Comment: Say the address to the root is http://asite.com/siteroot/ I'm trying to store that in the index.php file so I can access it in the other files. I tried assigning it to a global in the index.php but it's acting as though I'm assigning it in the file I'm calling it in. I'll try to revise the question a bit tomorrow

Comment: I've got the wrong idea of the $server variable, I was expecting it to return the URL for that initial file but it's using the URL as you'd see if the browser from the FallbackResource. So I need to store the URL from the index file somewhere to be called later. Will change the question tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Declare global variables in a file that's included at the beginning of every script, say in a config file.

```
/site 
/site/config.php 
/site/index.php
/site/subdir 
/site/subdir/anotherfile.php
```

eg:

config.php

```
<?php

$cfg = new stdClass();
$cfg->rooturi = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/siteroot';

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

echo $cfg->rooturi;

function somefunction(){
 global $cfg;

 echo 'In function '.$cfg->rooturi;
}

?>
```

subdir/anotherfile.php

```
   <?php
        require_once('../config.php'); // see '../' to go one level above as this file is in a subdirectory

        echo $cfg->rooturi;

        function somefunction(){
         global $cfg;

         echo 'In function '.$cfg->rooturi;
        }

  ?>
```

..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `index.php`:

```
$path = str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$baseUrl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $path;

$GLOBALS['rooturi'] = $baseUrl;
```

and then to load image:

```
<img src="<?php echo $GLOBALS['rooturi'] ?>/images/something.png" />
```